# CXF 2.7.0 web service deployment in Wildfly 10

Tags: deployment, jboss, cxf, ear, wildfly-10

Goal - Migrating EAR application from JBoss EAP 5 to Wildfly 10

Issue : Code has CXF 2.7.0 web service client code (to call third party web service) and its added to the EAR/lib folder. But during deployment, I am getting below exception

## log:

```
2016-02-26 12:17:48,075 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."rts-comcast-01.01.75.ear".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."rts-comcast-01.01.75.ear".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000071: Managed bean with a parameterized bean class must be @Dependent: class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.DataBindingProvider
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.checkType(ManagedBean.java:208)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractBean.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(AbstractBean.java:107)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(ManagedBean.java:122)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$AfterBeanDiscoveryInitializerFactory.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:136)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$AfterBeanDiscoveryInitializerFactory.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:127)
at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

## beans-xml

I have added below beans-xml to the META-INF and WEB-INF as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"  
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"  
  bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
```

## Alternate try

I was in a doubt whether the given libs are getting loaded to the application and want confirm my dependencies are good. so made a sample web application and loaded all the CXF jar files this time to WEB-INF/lib folder itself and deployed this time also the same issue as mentioned above

## CXF version in Wildfly 10

Wildfly 10 comes with CXF 3.1.4, but i have given my needed jars in my lib folder and did not mention any container provided CXF modules, to ensure CXF version in libs to load.

Could some provide an insight where I am doing wrong? Thanks for your help

After searching for a while i added the below config changes in jboss-deployment-strucutre.xml and still having issues. Please use this link for detailed information
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/268163

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I am facing the same problem and cannot get it to work in any way. Do you have any news?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolved after adding proper exclusion entries of container provided CXF3.1.4 and provided CXF version 2.7 or 2.4.4 (not sure about other lower versions)

jboss-deployment-structure.xml must be in the parent level META-INF in case your application has multiple modules (JAR, WAR, MDB)

These are my entries:

```
    <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies     -->
    <exclusions>
       <!-- Exclude Version cxf of JBOSS -->
       <module name="org.apache.cxf" />
       <!-- Exclude JAVA EE of JBOSS (javax.ws..) => Add dependency javax.annotation -->
       <module name="javaee.api" />

       <!-- Exclude RestEasy conflict (javax.ws.rs.ext.RunDelegate) -->
       <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />

       <!-- module name="org.apache.log4j" />
       <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/ -->
       <module name="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
       <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs"/>
       <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-cdi"/>
       <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.jackson-provider"/>
       <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-atom-provider"/>
       <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider"/>
       <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider"/>
       <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider"/>
       <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jsapi"/>
       <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider"/>
       <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-yaml-provider"/>
       <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl"/>
       <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-jaxrs"/>
       <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl"/>
       <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-xc"/>
       <module name="org.codehaus.jettison"/>
       <module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
    </exclusions>
```